# Remainder Theorem / Factor Theorem

Tags: polynomials

Hi Math Stack Exchange Community!

I'm having a hard time approaching this question.

"The polynomial $x^4 + px^3 + qx^2 + rx + 6$ is exactly divisible by each of $x-1$, $x-2$ and $x-3$. Find the values of $p, q$ and $r$."

So far I've developed one way of approach: make the polynomial $f(x)$, and show that $f(a), f(b)$ and $f(c)$ are $0$, or something like that. I am stuck, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What was the result of your attempt? Your idea was to set $f(1) = f(2) = f(3)=0$, where does this lead us then?

Comment: Your approach is fine. Let $f(1)=f(2)=f(3)=0$ and you will obtain a linear system in $p,q,r$. You have to solve such linear system.

Comment: @MattiP.- It gives us linear equations in p,q,r

Comment: @MattiP. should I solve it as simultaneous equations? Will row reduction work?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: You may get last factor quite easily, let the last root be m then $m.1.2.3=6$
$\Rightarrow$ $m=1$
And get the value of $p,q,r$ using the roots.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

Given a polynomial of degree $4$,  $3$ real roots are given, hence the $4$th root is real, say $a.$

Then

$p(x):=$

$x^4 +px^3+ qx^2+rx +6=$

$(x-1)(x-2)(x-3)(x-a).$

$6= (-1)\cdot (-2) \cdot (-3) \cdot (-a);$

$a=1;$

Compare the coefficients of $x^3,x^2$,and $x$ to find $p,q, r.$

Comment: Hi! I get how you got a. I just expanded the entire thing, and I got p = -7, q = 17, and r = -17. However, I was just wondering if it was possible to do this through row reduction echelon form? I got p = 7, q = -17, and r = 17 when I tried to do RREF. Please advise! Thank you!

Comment: E.Stafford.Do not know.Pick 3 values for x , and get 3 eqs. for p,q,r, whichever way you want to solve them.Not a bit shorter to compare coefficients of corresponding powers of x in (x-1)^2(x-2)(x-3) with p(x)?